# Only chrome is extremely slow when browsing

Tags: google-chrome, performance

Whenever I use Chrome, it is extremely slow trying to load pages. 
I noticed at the bottom it always tries to establish a secure connection (even if I browse to non-secure sites). It often just times out.

This ONLY happens in Chrome. For example Edge and Firefox are quite quick.

It *could* be related to Norton anti-virus (which I recently installed) but they swear it is not.

Also I do not run Comodo Dragon.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: BTW, I have completely disabled Norton and it does not solve the problem. I also did not see any other firewall application running. Finally I tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome. (none of these worked)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I will do in this case..

Disable and uninstall any themes for Chrome.

Goto Settings and then remove all the search providers apart from Google(or whichever one prefers)

Go to Add Ins and remove the disabled add ins and the one I don't use, including the one which have a warning sign beside them.

Clear the cache of Chrome.

Restart and test.

Comment: Removing search providers will not help with this issue.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of those search providers which fill up the browser with unwated ads, hence I suggested that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to launch the chrome in clean boot to see if the issue is on the chrome, or is on some conflicts.

Try the safe boot and clean boot to see if the issue still occurs.
(1) Log on as administrator
(2) `Win+R` and type `msconfig`
(3) We will get the window of `System Configuration`
(4) Select `General` tab
(5) Select `Selective startup`, then uncheck `Load startup items`
(5) Then select `Services` tab.
(6) Check `Hide all Microsoft services` checkbox.
(7) Click `Disable all`
(8) Select `Startup tab`, and click `Open Task Manager`.
(9) Make sure that `Startup` tab is selected.
(10)On the selected tab, right-click each startup program one-by-one to disable them.
(11)Close `Task Manager` when done and go back on `System Configuration` box, click `OK`.
(12)Then restart the machine.

You can just run other program, to see where does the issue happen.

Hope it can help you.